# What is this sound coming from my laptop?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop, which is making a weird "electricity" sound when doing something intensive like playing a game, what I have excluded as the source of the sound:
The motherboard has been replaced on this laptop, and the sound was there before the replacement too, so it cannot be the motherboard.

The HDD has also been replaced, but, it is the same model as the old one, so maybe this model makes that sound? The HDD model is st1000lm035-1rk172

I have nothing installed on the HDD, it is empty, everything is on my SSD, and as far as I know, an SSD does not make any sound. Could an SSD make coil whine?

I thought it was coil whine at first, but since the motherboard has been replaced and the sound is sitll present, what could it be?

This is not the fans, this sound is coming from the lower right corner of the laptop, which is exactly where the HDD and SSD is.

[Sound](https://clyp.it/m22gy31y)

The high pitched sound at the start is my bird so don't worry about that

Comment: even though your HDD has no content, if you've connected it, then it's active. could be the HDD.

Comment: If your bird is a parrot and a ventriloquist, maybe it's making the sound and throwing its voice so it seems to come from your computer.  :-)  It's hard to tell from the recording, but it sounds like it must be something motorized.  There are only a few such items, including the fan and HDD.  If you've localized it to the HDD area, that's it.  Some drives are noisy.  Use something like a piece of dowel as a stethoscope; one end on the HDD, the other against you head next to your ear.  That should confirm whether it's the source.

Comment: Hahaha, I sure hope it's not my bird :)